# VSCode adn Javascript: cannot connect to the target at localhost:9222

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

I am trying to follow debugging setup for Javascript from VSCode website
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/browser-debugging#_open-link-command
This is missing a lot of information, when I try to copy the launch.json Configuration from the website, I get the error `VSCode and Javascript: cannot connect to the target at localhost:9222`
If I use my own launch.json configuration, I cannot hit any of the breakpoints, the breakpoints all turn into white circles while debugging

First question:
Why is URL pointing to "http://localhost:8080"? Does VSCode automatically launch a server? Do I need to download an extension for this? Whereas in the first configuration, "http://localhost/test/index.html" is pointing to my XAMPP server

Second Question:
Looks like it's not starting edge with debugging enabled, **where in VSCode can I add this line? `edge.exe --remote-debugging-port=9222 --user-data-dir=remote-debug-profile`** is it not automatically started with this? Can I specify the edge executable path in launch.json?

Third Question:
I also tried adding the absolute path of edge with this property `"runtimeExecutable" : "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft\\Edge\\Application\\msedge.exe --remote-debugging-port=9222 --user-data-dir=remote-debug-profile"` and changing from `attach` to `launch` but I get the error `unable to launch browser, available auto-discovered versions are ["stable"]` how do I enter the exact path and arguments here?

My Launch.json is below that does not allow breakpoints to be hit

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "msedge",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch Edge Against Localhost",
            "url": "http://localhost/test/index.html",
            "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Launch.json From VSCode website that causes the error

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "msedge",
            "request": "attach",
            "name": "Attach to browser",
            "port": 9222,
            "url": "http://localhost:8080",
            "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
        }
    ]
}
```

index.html is below

```
<head>
    <title>Read Text File</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div id="myDynamicTable"></div>
    <script>

         window.onload = () => {
              document.write("TEST:");
         }
    </script>  
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(ﾉ °益°)ﾉ 彡 ┻━┻

Have you installed node.JS?

Comment: oh deerrrrrrrppppp

Comment: I have the same problem, but I installed node.JS (at the first time an old version installed VScode with that version, and later I have updated to the most recent version), but still the same. :\

Comment: honestly I recommend running a node server, `npm install`, `npm start` and debug in the browser `devTools` not through VSCode.